# Ubuntu 12.04 Realtek RTL8188E Wireless Card Not Detected

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, wubi

I have Ubuntu 12.04 (WUBI) on my Toshiba Satellite.  I have a Realtek RTL8188E Wireless LAN 802.11n. The internet works fine when I plug it in using a ethernet cable, but my laptop doesn't even search for wifi.  I have Windows 7 and my wifi works fine.  How do I make my wireless internet work?

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280 
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
```

Comment: I mean that I dual boot with Windows 7 and the wireless internet works fine on it.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score 4):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

I suggest you download this to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.12.2/backports-3.12.2-1.tar.bz2 Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
```

Your wireless should now be working. You will have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later linux-image, after reboot, re-compile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.12.2-1/
make clean
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
```

If the message logs say you need firmware:

```
dmesg | grep rtl
```

Download and install it with:

```
wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.106_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb 
sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee && sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
```

Comment: I had to go through all of the firmware stuff, but eventually got it to work on Debian 7 as well.  Thank you!

Comment: doesn't work... http://paste.ubuntu.com/8069197/

Comment: @Andrew What kernel version are you running? uname -r

Comment: 3.13.0.34-generic humm it is unstable.

Comment: @chili555 https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics  sudo dpkg i "name.deb", sudo apt-get -f install, sudo dpkg i "name.deb"  that is how I got my touchpad working.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/1.7.4-0ubuntu1

Comment: @Andrew The driver rtl8188ee is built-in to 3.13.0-xx; there is no need to try to backport an _earlier_ driver. If it is not working as expected, something else is wrong. I suggest you start your own new question and I'll be happy to help. Please bring along your bounty, too!

Comment: @chili555 I don't know how to bring bounty.

Comment: @chili555 this is one of the worst computer that I have work with to get Linux working right.

Comment: @chili555 you have no plan to help me?

Comment: @Andrew Did you start your own new question? Link??

Comment: @chili555 I was looking at your profile and you like doing networking things....  Guess what I got it working...  But I don't have a firmware and the latency = 0. is a firmware needed? when I do this command `sudo lshw -C network`  it out puts this other than the *s for the IP. http://paste.ubuntu.com/8085472/

Comment: That is why it wasn't working  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314434

Comment: @chili555 http://askubuntu.com/questions/513217/issures-with-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5105-laptop

Comment: Instead of jumping through all these hoops of compiling your own kernel you can just install the `linux-generic-lts-trusty` meta-package, which gives you a v3.13 kernel.

Comment: @Andrew The driver rtl8188ee doesn't require firmware. I think you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

First time that I tried, I got this message:

> CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support

Well, I'm brazilian and here Ubuntu calls "desktop" as "Área de trabalho" (with spaces and acute) and the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367838/compiling-error-while-installing-realtek-rtl8111e-in-64-bit-13-10-config-x86-x) saved me.