# Do kernel backports need to be reapplied each time kernel updates to new version?

Tags: wireless, kernel, backport

When a user backports a driver from a new kernel (as detailed [here](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Documentation)), does this backport need to be re-applied each time the kernel updates, e.g. if there was an automatic security update from kernel version `3.8.0-34-generic` to `3.8.0-35-generic`, would this break the user's backport? and thus require the user to reapply the backport?

(hence if the backport was to make wifi work, the wifi could die after an automatic kernel upgrade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the backported driver needs to be recompiled for each successive kernel update. After rebooting into the newer kernel, the process is, roughly:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.12-whatever
make clean
make defconfig-rtlwifi  <--or whichever driver suite you are building
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtlwhichever
```

Of course, adjust the process for your exact circumstances. Here is a post describing the process: [Ubuntu 12.04 Realtek RTL8188E Wireless Card Not Detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397983/ubuntu12-04-realtek-rtl8188e-wireless-card-not-detected/)

Comment: thanks for confirming this. I just lost my wifi when the kernel updated automatically for a security update, and managed to get it back by re-applying the backport.