# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using RTL8188e Wireless Connection is Flaky

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dual-boot

I just did a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual boot on Toshiba S55-a5358 laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed.

I had problems with dual boot so had to use boot-repair.
Also had problems with getting the wireless to work and this answer by chilli555 worked:

[Ubuntu 12.04 Realtek RTL8188E Wireless Card Not Detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397983/ubuntu12-04-realtek-rtl8188e-wireless-card-not-detected)

However the wireless on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is very flaky, slow and drops.

```
$ dmesg | grep rtl
[    7.282473] rtl8188ee 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    7.289730] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[    7.953254] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    7.953400] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[  594.241828] rtlwifi:rtl_watchdog_wq_callback():<0-0> AP off, try to reconnect now
[  928.494384] rtlwifi:rtl_watchdog_wq_callback():<0-0> AP off, try to reconnect now
[ 1163.316277] rtlwifi:addbareq_rx():<10000-1> sta is NULL
[ 1360.990311] rtlwifi:rtl_watchdog_wq_callback():<0-0> AP off, try to reconnect now
```

The wireless on Windows 8 works super fast and no drops.   I need help in getting the wireless to work consistently and fast on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thank you in advance.

As Per chilli555's comment:

```
azhar@azhar-Satellite-S55-A:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlan -e reason | tail -n25
Feb  4 11:56:51 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2629.951397] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c8:cb:b8:f0:76:70 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=8)
Feb  4 11:56:51 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2629.951794] wlan0: associated
Feb  4 11:56:51 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Feb  4 11:56:51 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Feb  4 11:56:51 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Feb  4 11:56:51 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): roamed from BSSID C8:CB:B8:F0:76:F0 (HUB) to C8:CB:B8:F0:76:70 (HUB)
Feb  4 11:58:07 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [100 20 40]
Feb  4 11:58:07 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed') [40]
Feb  4 11:58:08 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> Policy set 'HUB' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Feb  4 11:58:08 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> Policy set 'HUB' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Feb  4 11:59:42 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2800.378747] wlan0: Connection to AP c8:cb:b8:f0:76:70 lost
Feb  4 11:59:42 azhar-Satellite-S55-A wpa_supplicant[1409]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c8:cb:b8:f0:76:70 reason=4
Feb  4 11:59:42 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Feb  4 11:59:42 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2801.758438] wlan0: authenticate with c8:cb:b8:f0:a7:10
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2801.777780] wlan0: send auth to c8:cb:b8:f0:a7:10 (try 1/3)
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2801.781551] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2801.785467] wlan0: associate with c8:cb:b8:f0:a7:10 (try 1/3)
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2801.790905] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c8:cb:b8:f0:a7:10 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A kernel: [ 2801.791305] wlan0: associated
Feb  4 11:59:43 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Feb  4 11:59:45 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Feb  4 11:59:45 azhar-Satellite-S55-A NetworkManager[1368]: <info> (wlan0): roamed from BSSID C8:CB:B8:F0:76:70 (HUB) to C8:CB:B8:F0:A7:10 (HUB)
```

Another comment, the Wireless connection Applet "Bars" keep going up and down.
FYI, this does not happen on Windows 8 or my other Ubuntu laptop (ASUS) also running 12.04 LTS.

Also getting the following results:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6875216/

Comment: Right after it disconnects, please run: cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlan -e reason | tail -n25. Paste the result here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Hi,  Any hope for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to make a comment that for me the drivers for Realtek RTL8188EE downloaded from :

```
http://152.104.125.41/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2722
```

worked giving me a stable connection.

The backported driver as linked in the initial question did not give a stable connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have administrative privileges over the router, I'd suggest you change the encryption from mixed mode WPA and WPA2 to single mode WPA2-AES only. I'd also experiment with 802.11N disabled; use B and G only. I'd also turn of 'auto channel' and select a fixed channel such as 1 or 11.

You could also try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee swenc=1
```

If this helps, we can write a .conf file and make it permanent.

In your syslog, we see the device roaming from one band in the access point to another:

> (wlan0): roamed from BSSID C8:CB:B8:F0:76:F0 (HUB) to
>   C8:CB:B8:F0:76:70 (HUB)

We might try another parameter. This one is very hard to temporarily load so we'll write the conf file, reboot and try it. If it doesn't help, we'll simply delete our conf file:

```
sudo -i
echo "options cfg80211 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=Y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Since it didn't work, let's try another parameter:

```
sudo -i
rm /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
echo "options mac80211 probe_wait_ms=3000"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/mac80211.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I do not have access to the router so cannot configure the router.  Disabling of 802.11N/auto channel on,off needs to be done on router or wireless driver on the laptop? If it can be done on the laptop can you give me the commands? the driver parameters swenc=1 did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: didn't work.  Still disconnecting :( with reason=1, 3 and 4.

Comment: Update: I spent $10 and bought a RaLink RT5370 Wireless USB.  I turned off the internal wireless and now I have stable wireless on my ubuntu boot.