# Internet not working properly?

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu a few days back. I got rid of Windows completely, and I'm only using Linux now.

Everything works with Ubuntu, but I believe the wireless driver could possibly be outdated for my card or something, and I'm still fairly new to Linux and its commands (terminal).

Everyday the internet will cut out, but it still says I have a connection. It will just start loading web pages really slow, and then make me reload it. After a minute it will fix itself and start loading fast again.

Could this be a driver issue? I can load my info here if anyone needs it, but you'll have to tell me the commands for it. Hopefully we can get this resolved, because apparently it effects games also. :)

Thank you.

The command gave me this information:

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)

In response to Alexunder; It's a Toshiba Satellite C75D-A.

Comment: In order to start the process, we need to identify your wireless device. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280  The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my keyboard on the same key with backslash. Thanks.

Comment: what ubuntu version did u install

Comment: I installed Ubuntu version 13.10

Answer (score 0):

Well,try to search for a tool named "additional drivers" and see if it finds any proprietary driver for wireless(especially with broadcoms).
Other solutions right now i cannot see.
And in the future,try to tell us more about ur system(others might need that info to know before to answer)

Comment: In additional drivers I only have display drivers, and I'm already using 1 of them. :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/397983/ubuntu12-04-realtek-rtl8188e-wireless-card-not-detected                             It looks like there are more ppl with your issue,so try to look at that link and the way that guy explains how to manually install the driver for your particular device.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I just followed the directions, so we'll see how it goes. I'll post back to this topic to let you know the output.