# Ubuntu 15.04 RTL8188EE Slow/Unreliable Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04, realtek-wireless

Hey guys I'm having some issue with my `rtl8188ee` network card. On Windows I get ~30-40 Mb/s whereas on Ubuntu 15.04 I get ~5 Mb/s. However, the issue comes and goes; often after disconnecting and reconnecting my WiFi temporarily jumps to the proper speed, only to recede again shortly.

In search for an answer I came across [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397983/ubuntu-12-04-realtek-rtl8188e-wireless-card-not-detected); however I was unable to properly compile the driver (here's [the error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11820880/) I get when running `make`).

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could manage to compile the driver properly, or if anyone has another way to fix the slow WiFi speeds in Ubuntu 15.04.

In order to give as much information as possible, here are some diagnostic information:

`uname --all`:

```
Linux david-Lenovo-H535 3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 09
   serial: c0:3f:d5:72:be:6c
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:46 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
 *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 28:e3:47:60:76:6f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=3.19.0-21-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:48 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea03fff
```

[some guy's wireless info script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11820913/)

## **Edit**

I successfully installed the new driver thanks to @Pilot6 but problem persists. For more information, my download is the only speed affected. Upload is consistent at 10 Mb/s. I really have no clue what to do at this point. I know the hardware is fine because in Windows I don't have any issues with wireless.

## Second Edit

Disabling IPv6 worked for a while but speeds dropped back down again. Problem remains intermittent. I don't think this has to do with the wireless repeater I'm using because all other devices work fine. Further, upload speeds have been entirely consistent, so I doubt it has to do with the signal or interference.

Alas, 5 Mb/s is sufficient for my daily routine. I only hope a future update will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a driver from my ppa. It should build.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

Comment: It built so I'm marking this as accepted. I'll have to wait and see if the new driver even fixes the issue though.

Comment: So my wifi is still not working. With the new driver it started at 20 Mb/s but dropped to 6 Mb/s. Interestingly my upload has been consistently 10 Mb/s with both drivers. ~~I'll open a new question since this one was about the driver not compiling~~. On second thought I'll edit this one.

Comment: You can try to install 4.1.1 kernel as mentioned in the other question. But I doubt that it solves the issue, since there is actually same driver. But it is worth trying. @DavidEtler

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! +1

Comment: @DavidEtler what worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try to install latest kernel 4.1.1 from here:http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.1-unstable/

I have a rtl8723be and after updating to this kernel all problems were solved, now the speed is very good and the wifi is not disconnecting.

Comment: I would but I'm not comfortable using an unstable build of the kernel. Just don't want to deal with other possible headaches.

Comment: @DavidEtler But you can at least test if it helps, then remove that kernel, if it does not. That will give directions for me too if it is worth effort to update the driver in ppa.

Comment: @Pilot6 Okay, I'll try it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I installed the new kernel but when I boot into it I can't get X to run. I don't think I installed it properly; I've never manually installed a kernel image before.

Comment: Did you install image and header generic files for your arch? If you have a proprietary video driver, it may not build correctly. You can always remove these kernel packages from console.

Comment: I am using a proprietary video driver. I did remove them. Sadly I couldn't test the WiFi. Maybe a future update will fix my Wifi, this is frustrating.

Comment: I have installed today this kernel and work good for 8 hours. Install the kernel in this order:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.1-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.1-040101_4.1.1-040101.201507030635_all.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.1-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.1-040101-generic_4.1.1-040101.201507030635_amd64.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.1-unstable/linux-image-4.1.1-040101-generic_4.1.1-040101.201507030635_amd64.deb
after this `sudo update-grub` and the reboot.

Comment: That's looks correct. You can remove it using `dpkg -r` <package_name>. Not file name, but only package name. I am leaving now sry.

Comment: Okay. I'm turning off the proprietary graphics driver and trying the new kernel again.

Comment: The problem persists even with the new kernel.

Comment: In this case there seem to be no solution so far. @DavidEtler

Answer (score 0):

I have a new HP 17-x121dx that has an RTL8188ee and I've had nothing but problems with the wifi not connecting. After a week of searching and trying different suggestions, the one that seems to have worked is below....

Edit blacklist.conf that is located at /etc/modprobe.d/ and at the bottom of the file I added: blacklist acer-wmi

After rebooting the wifi connected automatically.

Hope this helps others who have been battling with this.