# Weak and unstable wifi after installing Ubuntu on Windows machine

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

Recently installed Ubuntu on a windows machine and I am getting really weak and unstable wifi signal, that previously ran perfectly on Windows, prior to installing ubuntu.

My machine is an HP Envy 15. My Ubuntu version is 14.04 (Unity). The wifi seems to magically disconnect at random times or take a really really long time to load a page, I'm basically getting dial up speeds.

I appreciate any help on resolving this as this is really frustrating. Let me know if I can include any additional information from terminal that may help.

Command:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:197d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please see edited.

Comment: I marked is duplicate. You can try these solutions. But you are unfortunate with a wireless adapter. It is not supported very well in linux.

Comment: Try what solutions?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/644430/ubuntu-15-04-rtl8188ee-slow-unreliable-wifi