# install kernel version 4.1.1 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel

I have followed this tutorial

http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/07/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-1-1-in-linux.html

to install install 4.1.1 kernel but at the end when i checked my kernel versions by

```
uname -r
```

I am still seeing the old kernel

```
4.4.0-62-generic
```

Comment: restart the pC and check it

Comment: @TamilSelvanC i have restarted it 3 time. and also updated the grub.

Comment: Why do you need that kernel?

Comment: @Pilot6 Because of this; http://askubuntu.com/questions/883610/wifi-speed-is-just-10-kb-on-ubuntu-but-work-fine-on-windows . There Mark suggested another question with, among others, this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/644453/589808 . In a nutshell, Waris, please don't! **You already have a newer and proper kernel**

Comment: @Pilot6 I need this kernel to resolve my wifi problem.                                                                  http://askubuntu.com/questions/883610/wifi-speed-is-just-10-kb-on-ubuntu-but-work-fine-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Grub always loads the latest kernel. You need to manually select the 4.1.1 kernel from advanced options of grub menu.

If you want the 4.1.1 kernel to be default, you will need to remove all newer kernels from your system.

Please note that the 4.1.1 kernel is not supported, and questions about problems with it are off-topic at this site.