# Asus Z87 PRO - fan speed detector - failed to 'make' nct6775 drivers

Tags: drivers, asus, fancontrol

I want to monitor the fans in my HTPC due to a recent and inexplicable temperature increase of 5+ degrees C.
Package 'lm-sensors' does not detect fan sensors. After some investigation I found there are drivers available for Nuvoton chip in my mobo Z87 PRO:

https://github.com/groeck/nct6775

When making/compiling I get the following error:

```
~/Z87 Drivers/nct6775-master$ sudo make
**arch/x86/Makefile:136: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:652: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-        protector not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Drivers/nct6775-master'.  Stop.
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2**
~/Z87 Drivers/nct6775-master$
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Does this apply to you?][1] This could be a double.... see here.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/367838/compiling-error-while-installing-realtek-rtl8111e-in-64-bit-13-10-config-x86-x

Comment: WOW WOW WOW      a 'space' in the folder name caused that mess ! ! ! ! ! !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following sequence:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
cd ~/Z87\ Drivers/nct6775-master
make clean
make
sudo make install
```